# how to call struct into my post Request and how to bind the data

Tags: json, swiftui, data-binding, binding

```
struct LogIn: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
    let success: Bool
    let successCode, httpstatusCode: Int
    let developerMessage, userMessage, header: String
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let userID: Int
    let name, email, phone, dob: String
    let status: Bool
    let password: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "UserID"
        case name = "Name"
        case email = "Email"
        case phone = "Phone"
        case dob = "DOB"
        case status = "Status"
        case password = "Password"
    }
}
```

this is my json struct and my link is [there](https://782487cd-de44-486f-b859-c3a343212397.mock.pstmn.io/V1/Users/SignIn) .. and i wonder how to bind the data in my login page

i have added my login base Code here for reference.

```
VStack{
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20){
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
                    
                   
                        
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .padding()
                    
                 
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                  self.manager.PostAPI(email: self.email, password: self.password)
                    shownext = true
                }){
                    Text("Sign In")
                       
                }

                
            }
            
        }
        
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showsignup) {
              Sign_Up()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFP) {
              ForgetPssword()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shownext, content: {
            Dummy(selection: self.$shownext)
        })
```

need to help for bind the value also.  i just wonder how to do bind  the login page. am a newbie of the Swiftui and IOS also. help me out of this.

Comment: Please add your login page code here. Try to create a [mre]. There is not enough information here to provide a definitive answer [ask].

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378663/how-to-call-struct-into-my-post-request-and-how-to-bind-the-data

Comment: check the above link which i have commanded .. i can't add that much of code here..

Comment: kindly help me out of that

Comment: If there is to much code, you have to boil it down to the essential parts. It will be very hard for someone trying to help you without more information how your code is structured.

Comment: i have added some base code only here. check it out